# Sum of Hermite polynomials

Tags: summation, factorial, hermite-polynomials

I am trying to find a closed form (or the tightest upper bound possible) for the following sum:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{H_{2n}(x)w^n}{(2n+1)!}
$$

From the equalities $
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n}(x)w^n}{n!}=e^{2xw-w^2}
$ and $H(-x)=(-1)^nH(x)$ I can obtain
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{H_{2n}(x)w^n}{(2n)!}=\frac{e^{2xw-w^2}+e^{-2xw-w^2}}{2}
$$
Which is close but not what I want.
I thought of using the recurrence relation on the hermite polynomials or the identity $H_n'(x)=2nH_{n-1}(x)$ but I couldn't find a solution.
This sum looks like it should have a closed form but I am currently stuck, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Thank you! I didn't think of using the derivative in regards to w though it should have been obvious. I will see if this is easy to integrate.

Comment: Sadly I see no way to express this without any erf or other nonelementary integrals.

Comment: @Svyatoslav: There is a mistake in your integrand. You should replace $t^2$ with $t$ and $t^4$ with $t^2$. See my proposed solution.

Comment: @user12030145, yes, you are right. Thank you for catching this; I removed my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as the previous answer is just CAS, I will offer a detailed proof as an alternative.
Posit:
$$f(x, w) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{H_{2n}(x)w^n}{(2n+1)!}  \tag{1}$$
$$g(x, w) = w f(x, w^2) \tag{2}$$
Then observe that for $w$ in any given compact of the complex plane, the series of derivarives in $w$ is dominated in norm by a geometric series, so that $g(x, w)$ can be derived term-by-term. Now:

\begin{align} \frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{w}}(x,w) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{H_{2n}(x) w^{2n}}{(2n)!}\\
&= \frac{e^{- (w - x)^2} + e^{- (w + x)^2}}{2}\,e^{x^2}
\end{align}

by use of the classic generating function $e^{2xt-t^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty H_n(x)\frac{t^n}{n!}$.

whence, by an obvious change of variables ($v=w \pm x$):

\begin{align}g(x,w)=g(x,w) -g(x,0) &= \frac{e^{x^2}}{2} \left(\int_{-x}^{w-x} e^{-t^2} dt + \int_{x}^{w+x} e^{-t^2}dt\right) \\
&=  \frac{e^{x^2}}{4}  \sqrt{\pi } \left((\text{erf}(w-x)+\text{erf}(x)) + (\text{erf}(w+x)-\text{erf}(x))\right)\\
&=  \frac{e^{x^2}}{4}  \sqrt{\pi } \left(\text{erf}(w-x) + \text{erf}(w+x)\right) \tag{3}
\end{align}

hence, choosing $w>0$:

$$f(x, w) = \frac{g(x, \sqrt{w})}{\sqrt{w}} = \frac{e^{x^2}}{4}  \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{w} } \left(\text{erf}(\sqrt{w}-x) + \text{erf}(\sqrt{w}+x)\right)$$

which is the CAS answer.

(Edit)
For $w<0$, $(2)-(3)$ being true for any complex $w$, we can write:

$$f(x, w) = f(x, (i\sqrt{-w})^2) = -i\frac{g(x, i\sqrt{-w})}{\sqrt{-w}} = -i \frac{e^{x^2}}{4}  \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{-w} } \left(\text{erf}(i\sqrt{-w}-x) + \text{erf}(i\sqrt{-w}+x)\right)$$

which can also be directly inferred from $(3)$ by analytic continuation.

Finally for $w=0$, the answer is  obvious: $f(x, 0) = H_0(x)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

With Mathematica:

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{w^n H_{2 n}(x)}{(1+2 n)!}=\frac{e^{x^2} \sqrt{\pi } \left(\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{w}-x\right)+\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{w}+x\right)\right)}{4
   \sqrt{w}}$$

Comment: To expand a bit on my question: the right hand side you give here is what I was originally trying to compute. I am looking for a closed form without infinite sums or nonelementary integrals. There may not be any such closed form but I was hopeful since there seems to be lots of such formulas for sums of hermite polynomials.

Comment: @Urmnaf .Bad news,no Hope for Erf function to get elementary function.

Comment: I had not seen it like that but it would indeed entail an elementary function for erf... Case closed I guess.

Comment: It depends on what you consider to be an elementary function. There is no universally accepted definition of this expression. Even 'closed-form' is a controversal one. Erf is however a very commonly used function in all scientific fields, notably statistics.